# clojure rename-keys in nested structure

Tags: clojure

Suppose I have a nested structure, something like this:

```
{:data1 
    {:categories [
        {:name "abc" :id 234 :desc "whatever"} 
        {:name "def" :id 456 :desc "nothing"}]
    }
  :data2 {...}
  :data3 {...}
}
```

And I need to transform the key names in the maps. I can transform the top level keys like this:

```
(rename-keys mymap {:data1 :d1})
```

But I'm not sure how to rename keys nested more deeply in the data structure (say I want to rename the :desc field to :description).

I'm pretty sure that zippers are the answer but can't quite figure out how to do it, or if there's a more straightforward way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Same as Brian Carper's solution, except the walk namespace already has a specific function for this purpose. All keys at all levels are changed, be they nested inside any sort of collection or seq.

```
(:use 'clojure.walk)

(def x
  {:data1
   {:categories
    [{:desc "whatever", :name "abc", :id 234}
     {:desc "nothing", :name "def", :id 456}]},
   :data2
   {:categories
    [{:desc "whatever", :name "abc", :id 234}
     {:desc "nothing", :name "def", :id 456}]}})

(postwalk-replace {:desc :something} x)

{:data1
 {:categories
  [{:something "whatever", :name "abc", :id 234}
   {:something "nothing", :name "def", :id 456}]},
 :data2
 {:categories
  [{:something "whatever", :name "abc", :id 234}
   {:something "nothing", :name "def", :id 456}]}}
```

Answer (score 7):

`postwalk` is a pretty heavy sledgehammer in general, although it looks from your original question like you might need it. In many cases, you can perform updates in a nested structure with `update-in`:

```
user> (let [m {:foo {:deep {:bar 1 :baz 2}}}]
        (update-in m [:foo :deep] clojure.set/rename-keys {:baz :periwinkle}))
{:foo {:deep {:periwinkle 2, :bar 1}}}
```

Comment: Does this also work when I have a combination of vectors and maps in the data structure? Basically I have a json document that has been converted to clojure data structure and I need to transform it a bit before passing it along. This looks preferable because I'd like to be sure that I'm not renaming something accidentally.

Comment: I guess my problem is that I want to specify the full path but I also want it to apply to all vector indices along the way (hopefully that makes sense...)

Comment: Why is walk considered a sledgehammer ? Is this because of the 'all or nothing' approach, performance considerations, or something else entirely ?

Comment: If there's maps inside vectors inside maps, I don't think update-in will work on the maps inside the vector. This does work with walk.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to rename all `:desc` keys regardless of at which level of nesting they're located, this might work.  If you only want to rename `:desc` keys at a certain level of nesting, you'll need something slightly more sophisticated.

This only works because `clojure.set/rename-keys` currently does nothing (returns its first argument untouched) if its first argument isn't a map.

```
user> (require '[clojure [set :as set] [walk :as walk]])
nil

user> (def x {:data1
              {:categories
               [{:desc "whatever", :name "abc", :id 234}
                {:desc "nothing", :name "def", :id 456}]},
              :data2
              {:categories
               [{:desc "whatever", :name "abc", :id 234}
                {:desc "nothing", :name "def", :id 456}]}})
#'user/x

user> (walk/postwalk #(set/rename-keys % {:desc :description :id :ID}) x)
{:data1
 {:categories
  [{:name "abc", :ID 234, :description "whatever"}
   {:name "def", :ID 456, :description "nothing"}]},
 :data2
 {:categories
  [{:name "abc", :ID 234, :description "whatever"}
   {:name "def", :ID 456, :description "nothing"}]}}
nil
```

Comment: that's pretty nice; I'm not sure yet if it will work for my situation (yet) but cool either way.